# Sort multidimensional array based of the difference in the value

Tags: java, array, sorting, complexity

> Sort multidimensional array based of the difference in the value, if
>   value is same sort on first column.
>
> Constrains:
>
> No of rows can be any but fixed no of column ie 2.
>         Example:
>
> ```
> int arr[][] = new int[5][2]
>
>     [0] [1]
> [0]  0   6
> [1]  0   7
> [2]  4   5
> [3]  2   3
> [4]  0   1
> ```
>
> Final Output:
>
> ```
>     [0] [1]
> [0]  0   1
> [1]  2   3
> [2]  4   5
> [3]  0   6
> [4]  0   7
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> ```
> difference between: arr[0][1] - arr[0][0] -> 6-0 -> 6
> difference between: arr[1][1] - arr[1][0] -> 7-0 -> 7
> difference between: arr[2][1] - arr[2][0] -> 5-4 -> 1 — same length ie 1
> difference between: arr[3][1] - arr[3][0] -> 3-2 -> 1 — same length ie 1
> difference between: arr[4][1] - arr[4[0] -> 1-0 -> 1 — same length ie 1
> ```
>
> I want to sort on the difference, in cases where difference is same I
>   want to sort those with same difference on column [0]
>
> So in this case, the below 3 have same difference:
>
> ```
> difference between: arr[2][1] - arr[2][0] -> 5-4 -> 1 — same difference ie 1
> difference between: arr[3][1] - arr[3][0] -> 3-2 -> 1 — same difference ie 1
> difference between: arr[4][1] - arr[4[0] -> 1-0 -> 1 — same difference ie 1
> ```
>
> Need to sort the above 3 based on there column[0] value:
>
> ```
> arr[2][1] - arr[2][0] -> 5-4 -> 1 — value here is 4 ie arr[2][0] 
> arr[3][1] - arr[3][0] -> 3-2 -> 1 — value here is 2 ie arr[3][0]
> arr[4][1] - arr[4[0] -> 1-0 -> 1 — value here is 1 ie arr[4][0]
> ```
>
> So the the one with the least value in column[0] should be first, in
>   final output:
>
> ```
> arr[4][1] - arr[4[0]  -> 1-0 -> 1 ——> 1st
> arr[3][1] - arr[3][0]  -> 3-2 -> 1 ——> 2nd
> arr[4][1] - arr[4[0]  -> 1-0 -> 1 ——> 3rd 
> arr[0][1] - arr[0][0]  -> 6-0 -> 6 ——> 4th
> arr[1][1] - arr[1][0]  -> 7-0 -> 7 ——> 5th
> ```

I would like to know the time complexity of my code. In short, what is the complexity of sorting a 2D array? 1d array --> O(n.logn) 2d --> ?

```
private static int solve(int pathLength, int[][] floristIntervals) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(floristIntervals));
        Arrays.sort(floristIntervals, new Comparator<int[]>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                /*System.out.println(o1[0]);
                System.out.println(o1[1]);
                System.out.println(o2[0]);
                System.out.println(o2[1]);*/
                if(o2[1]-o2[0] == o1[1]-o1[0]){
                    if(o2[0] > o1[0]){
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
                if (o2[1]-o2[0] > o1[1]-o1[0])
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }

        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(floristIntervals));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Comparator → Total Ordening

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.

`compare({0, 1}, {0, 1}) == 1`

In its current form, the used comparator cannot return 0, and returns 1 for equals elements.

## Does not solve problem?

The example input gives this as output:

`[[0, 7], [0, 6], [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]`

```
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        if(o2[1]-o2[0] == o1[1]-o1[0]){
            if(o2[0] > o1[0]){
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        if (o2[1]-o2[0] > o1[1]-o1[0])
            return 1; // <-- should be -1
        else
            return -1; // <-- should be +1
    }
```

## Review

`pathLength` isn't used. What is it for?

The method `solve` is declared to return `int`, but doesn't.

Consider adding braces to all code blocks—including `if` and `else`. This will prevent errors from adding lines later.

`o1` and `o2` could be replaced with `lhs` (left-hand side) and `rhs` (right-hand side), but that's a bit nitpicking.

In order to implement returning 0 for equal elements, try using `Integer.compare`:

```
@Override
public int compare(int[] lhs, int[] rhs) {
    int rv = Integer.compare(lhs[1] - lhs[0], rhs[1] - rhs[0]);
    return rv != 0 ? rv : Integer.compare(lhs[0], rhs[0]);
}
```

## Time Complexity

Unchanged: \$O(n\ log\ n)\$ by virtue of the comparison function being \$O(1)\$.